# Image isn't displaying. What should I do?

Tags: html, css, image

This is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>portfolio website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,
    wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" 
    integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==
    " crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
    font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4t
    Mg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin=
    "anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</head>
<body>
    <!--hero section start-->

    <div class="hero">
        <nav>
            <h2 class="logo">Portfolio</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Subscribe</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css.

```
    *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("file://C:\Users\user\Desktop\pexels-cup-of-couple-6177571.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

I added an image to my css but for some reason it isn't showing.

Comment: To help track down problems like this you can use your browser's dev tools inspect facility and look at its console. You should see what the error is there.

Answer (score 1):

Change your image path to relative. For example:

```
.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("images/pexels-cup-of-couple-6177571.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

You can put your image inside 'images' folder.
The path in this example is called a relative path which means it is a local file, relative to our project and to our current working directory

Answer (score 0):

You should put image in your current working directory, And then use relative path of the image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```css
   *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hero{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1546641082-b3c3d4bfae25?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>portfolio website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,
    wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" 
    integrity="sha512-iBBXm8fW90+nuLcSKlbmrPcLa0OT92xO1BIsZ+ywDWZCvqsWgccV3gFoRBv0z+8dLJgyAHIhR35VZc2oM/gI1w==
    " crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
    font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1sCRPdkRXhBV2PBLUdRb4t
    Mg1w2YPf37qatUFeS7zlBy7jJI8Lf4VHwWfZZfpXtYSLy85pkm9GaYVYMfw5BC1A==" crossorigin=
    "anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</head>
<body>
    <!--hero section start-->

    <div class="hero">
        <nav>
            <h2 class="logo">Portfolio</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Subscribe</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is right but you need to call image from project folder, you can move image in same folder and then you can call it.
ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ
 background-image: url("./pexels-cup-of-couple-6177571.jpg");